# The type of styled-component does not match for "strict: true"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

When we use styled-component in TypeScript to inherit the Material-UI component, props type does not match.
How do I overwrite a style with styled-component?

There is a sample on how to inherit in the case of styled-component in the following link, but this sample will generate an error if it is set to `strict:true` in tsconfig setting.

If there is an answer to this issue, thank you.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13921